# mergesort, issue with recursive base case and ordering

Tags: python, recursion

I have made the following implementation in Python of the Mergesort algorithm:

```
def mergeSort(listNumbers,ini,end):
    if ini==end:
        return listNumbers
    else:
        mid=(ini+end)/2
        mergeSort(listNumbers,ini,mid)
        mergeSort(listNumbers,mid+1,end)
        merge(listNumbers,ini,mid,end)

def merge(listNumbersT,ini,mid,end):
    b=[]
    ind1=ini
    ind2=mid+1
    while ind1<=mid and ind2<=end:
        if listNumbersT[ind1]<listNumbersT[ind2]:
            b.append(listNumbersT[ind1])
            ind1=ind1+1
        else:
            b.append(listNumbersT[ind2])
            ind2=ind2+1
    while ind1<=mid:
        b.append(listNumbersT[ind1])
        ind1=ind1+1
    while ind2<=end:
        b.append(listNumbersT[ind2])
        ind2=ind2+1
    listNumbersT=b
    print listNumbersT

def main():
    l=[4,1,8,2,5,9,10]
    print mergeSort(l,0,len(l)-1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I do not know how to fix the base case of my recursive call to mergeSort, when I run the program it prints None; and the only way that I have to print the final the result is to add:

print listNumbersT

in the merge function, how can I fix this? also it seems it does not order the last elements of my list.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by making your sort in-place. In some places you were returning lists, other places not so much.

The revised `mergeSort` function looked like this:

```
def mergeSort(listNumbers,ini,end):
    if ini < end:
        mid=(ini+end)/2
        mergeSort(listNumbers,ini,mid)
        mergeSort(listNumbers,mid+1,end)
        merge(listNumbers,ini,mid,end)
```

That means the base case is when `ini >= end`, `listNumbers` remains unaltered.

At the end of the `merge` function I replaced your `listNumbersT = b` with:

```
    for i,value in enumerate(b):
        listNumbersT[ini + i] = value
```

which copies the elements of `b` back to the original `listNumbersT`.  Again, this make the changes "in-place" on the original list, and therefore doesn't need to return anything.

And that made the `main`:

```
def main():
    l=[4,1,8,2,5,9,10]
    mergeSort(l,0,len(l)-1)   # sort l in-place
    print l                   # [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

A minor tweak - by changing the beginning of the `mergeSort` function to

```
def mergeSort(listNumbers,ini=0,end=-1):
    if end < 0:
        end += len(listNumbers)
```

the invocation in `main` became simply:

```
mergeSort(l)
```

which makes it slightly easier for users.

Answer (score 0):

Not changing your code too much,

In your function `merge` the line `listNumbersT=b` reallocates the variable `listNumbersT` and for that reason you lose the values you have there, breaking your recursion.

To fix that, replace `listNumbersT=b` in your function `merge` by the following loop by.

```
for i,number in enumerate(b):
    listNumbersT[ini + i] = number
```

To obtain the correct return you need to have a return at the end of your mergeSort function, such as

```
def mergeSort(listNumbers,ini,end):
    if ini==end:
        return listNumbers
    else:
        mid=(ini+end)/2
        mergeSort(listNumbers,ini,mid)
        mergeSort(listNumbers,mid+1,end)
        merge(listNumbers,ini,mid,end)

    return listNumbers
```

However, `l` will be reordered in place, so you don't really need the return at the end of `mergeSort`.

Cheers

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that it does not sort the elements when I do that

Comment: I believe it is fixed now.